# Construct the tangent to a point on the parabola

Tags: geometry, tangent-line

**Problem:**

Given the following parabola, construct a tangent to point $P$. Justify the construction.

[image]

**Solution:**

Draw the line $PA$ which is perpendicular to the axis and intersects that axis at $B$. Mark off the distance $OB$ and use it to find point $C$. The line $PC$ is tangent to the parabola.

[image]

Basically my only justification that CP is tangent is that it *looks* really tangent. I have tried justifying my claim but can't seem to get anywhere. I have noticed that a circle can be constructed through points $PAC$. Let point $D$ be where $\circ PAC$ intersects the axis of the parabola. Then $\triangle CPD$ is an inscribed right triangle. This fact seems like it could be useful, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I can think of a couple of ways to prove this geometrically, but it depends on what properties you’re allowed to use. For instance, it’s a special case of the [two-points-two-tangents property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#2-points-2-tangents-property_of_a_parabola), which is itself a corollary of [Pascal’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem). It looks like one might be able to prove it using the [reflective property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Proof_of_the_reflective_property), too.

Comment: Neat construction! Note, though, that it fails at the vertex.

Comment: Interesting point, @amd. Say that $P$ is on the vertex. Then we can simply construct the perpendicular to the axis of the parabola, and we have arrived at the tangent. So we arrive at the tangent even faster :)

Comment: AP is the polar of C with respect to the parabola.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Justification: Consider a general parabola $y=ax^2$. Don't need to consider the $bx+x$ term as these terms only describe horizontal and vertical translations but they don't change the parabola's shape. Consider point of tangency $P$ with coordinates $(t,at^2)$ and point $B$ follows $(0,at^2)$. From here your point $C$ is then $(0,-at^2)$. Now the slope of tangent $PC$ can be found with the basic slope formula "rise over run" using the points $P$ and $C$, which then becomes $m=\frac{at^2--at^2}{t-0}$ which simplifies to $2at$. This is the same value as when you take the derivative of $y=ax^2$ and plug in $x=t$. PS, this is a really neat construction, I am thinking of putting this question to my students...

Comment: This is a great justification using analytic geometry. Do you know how we might justify it using purely geometrical means?

Comment: Yes, I know for sure that this can also be proven using properties of the parabola, meaning using focus and directrix, and no calculus. But....I have forgotten at the moment. Maybe somebody else on the forum can pitch in...:)

Answer (score 5):

Your supposition is correct.For parabola parametrized by $ (x,y)= (2 a t, a t^2)$ the slope at any point is $dy/dx=t$. It can be seen that tangent bisects the $x$ abscissa at tangent to vertex .. and the parabola vertex itself bisects (ordinate-central cutting point) line $ BOC.$

Answer (score 4):

Let point $C$ be such that $O$ is the midpoint of $BC$ on the parabola's axis.

I propose to take advantage of the interpretation of the parabola as a **quadratic Bézier curve** (https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/maths-linear-quadratic-relations/0/steps/12129). A basic property of the quadratic Bézier curve defined by $P,C,A$ ($P$ as origin, $A$ as endpoint, and $C$ as control point or "handle") is that the summit $O$ of the arc of parabola it defines is the midpoint of the midpoints of line segments $[CP]$ and $[CA]$.

The essential property of Bézier curve defined by $P,C,A$ in our case is that **$CP$ is tangent to the curve in $P$.**

The parametric equations of the curve can be given in the following form:

$$\binom{x}{y}=(1-t)^2\binom{x_P}{y_P}+2t(1-t)\binom{x_C}{y_C}+t^2\binom{x_A}{y_A}$$

for $0 \leq t \leq 1$. If $t=0$, we are in $P$. If $t=1$ we are in $A$.

It is important to check that the parabola passes through the midpoint $O$ of $BC$.

This will happen when $t=1/2$. In this case, the current point of the parabola is

$$\binom{x}{y}=\dfrac12\binom{x_C}{y_C}+(\dfrac14\binom{x_P}{y_P}+\dfrac14\binom{x_A}{y_A})=\dfrac12\binom{x_C}{y_C}+\dfrac12\binom{x_B}{y_B}$$

(using rules of barycentrical computations), i.e., the midpoint of line segment $CB$, that is to say point $O$, as desired.

Comment: I haven't heard of Bezier curves before this, but they look really interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

EternusVia. Here is another, but NON calculus approach: Consider point of tangency $P(t,at^2)$. Tangent PC passing through P is then of the form $y=mx+at^2-mt $ (verify!).Now intersecting the tangent with the parabola gives us the equation $ax^2=mx+at^2-mt,$ which simplifies to $ax^2-mx-at^2+mt=0.$ This equation is to have only one solution (at $P$) and so the Discriminant $D=b^2-4ac,$ of this equation must be zero. This gives $m^2-4a(-at^2+mt)=0$. Simplify gives $m^2-4amt+4a^2t^2=0$. Surprise...surprise, this equation is factorable as a perfect square: $(m-2at)^2=0$ from which $m=2at$ , etc...

Comment: I think that the Bezier curve interpretation I propose is equivalent to your presentation.

Comment: That's a very cool link. I need to study that when I get a break...

Answer (score 1):

Take a parabola: $$y=ax^2+bx+c$$

Differentiating gives us the slope equation: $$m=2ax+b$$

The slope is zero at the vertex so the $x$ value of the vertex is: $$x=\frac{-b}{2a}$$

Sub this into the parabola equation to get the $y$ value at the vertex. The vertex is: $$(\frac{-b}{2a},c-\frac{b^2}{4a})$$

Let's pick a point on the parabola $k$ above the vertex. So its $y$ value is: $$y=c-\frac{b^2}{4a}+k$$

Let's prove that the tangent intersects the axis of symmetry at: $$c-\frac{b^2}{4a}-k$$

Let's find the two $x$ values at: $y=c-\frac{b^2}{4a}+k$

Sub this value for $y$ into the parabola equation and use the quadratic formula to get your two values for $x$. $$x=\frac{-b}{2a}\pm \sqrt{\frac{k}{a}}$$

Let's use the one with the positive sign.

The point of tangency is : $$(\frac{-b}{2a}+\sqrt{\frac{k}{a}},c-\frac{b^2}{4a}+k)$$

Sub this $x$ value into the slope equation to get the slope of the tangent. It is: $$m=2\sqrt{ak}$$

Using the value for the slope and the point of tangency let's derive the equation of the tangent. $$y-c+\frac{b^2}{4a}-k=2\sqrt{ak}(x+\frac{b}{2a}-\sqrt{\frac{k}{a}})$$

We want to see where this tangent line intersects the axis. The axis is the line $x=\frac{-b}{2a}$. Sub $x=\frac{-b}{2a}$ into the tangent equation and solve for $y$.

$$y=c-\frac{b^2}{4a}-k$$

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most reasonable geometric justification would be to show that any ray coming parallel to the axis will reflect towards the focus, i.e. that the normal is the bisectriz of the angle EAF

For this it should be enough to check consistency of the construction. Perhaps the most important point is that FC is the same length that AF. This follows from the definition of parabola, because AF = AA' = DF' and then just by reflection in the origin DF' = FC.

From this, taking the circle centered in the focus, we build B and thus the normal AB. This is actually my common way to do the tangent and normal, but if only need the tangent, projection is fine, less clutter.

Ah, we have still not proven that angle BAF is half of EAF. Well, honestly I do not know what argument is more intuitive. We could just parallel translate AF pointing its arrow to B, and see that as AF=BF we have now a rombus, call it (AFBE'). That would be enough to my taste.

[image: activity https://www.geogebra.org/m/h4295ewq]

https://www.geogebra.org/m/h4295ewq

Comment: In the blackboard, to do the tangentm people prefers projection to the horizontal axis and then mid-point.